# After deploy taking time to reflect changes

Tags: amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-cloudfront

I have a project which is built-in ReactJs. and I am using s3 and CloudFront for deployment.
I am facing an issue whenever I deploy code after deployment it takes too much time to reflect changes. sometimes I have to manually clear browser cookies for the latest changes. Do I need to configure S3 or CloudFront settings?

Comment: Added answer see if this help you @AnkurPohekar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. Go to cloudfront :
2. Do invalidation of objects
3. Create entry `/*`

[image]

Reference : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serving-outdated-content-s3/