# Does AWS Cloudfront cache the entire web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Does AWS cloudfront cache the entire page? I would like to clear the cache based on the last time page modified ? Can I clear the cache based on Last-Modified or If-modified-since header values.

Comment: There is only option to invalidate cached using page link or media .

Comment: Hello @aviboy2006 Can you please elaborate more on how to clear the cache using page link or media? If you provide some example, that would be very helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713932/after-deploy-taking-time-to-reflect-changes/62733334#62733334 check this answer @user13984701